# On image sheaf of the evaluation map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let, $E$ be a coherent sheaf on a  polarized projective algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$ and  $ V \subset H^0(E)$ be a subspace.Let's denote the evaluation map as $f : V \otimes \mathcal O_X \to E$.

**Question $(1)$** : Is $Imf$  globally generated by global sections?Does it have nonnegative degree as a coherent sheaf?

**Question $(2)$** : Is it true that $H^0(Imf) = V$ ?(Or at least $H^0(Imf) \subset V$?)

**Question $(3)$** : Can we say that $ P(Imf ,t) , P(E, t) \geq 0$ for some $t >>0$ ?[ where $P( ,t)$ stands for  hilbert polynomial with respect to that fixed polarization ]

Can someone give me any reference?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: For 1), first part is correct, second will depend on your definition of degree. 2) is in general false. 3) is correct, since all Hilbert polynomials have leading term positive, so for large $t$, it is positive (I am assuming that $E\neq 0$).

Comment: @Mohan, Is it known  under what condition $(2)$ is true?What if $X$ is a $K3$ surface?

Comment: It can be false anywhere. For example take a projective variety of dimension $d$ and and an ample line bundle $L$. Then large powers of $L$ has large number of sections (grows like a polynomial of degree $d$). But, you can always find $V\subset H^0(L^n)$ of dimension $d+1$ which generates $L^n$. So, image of $f$ would be all of $L^n$ with too many sections.